# How to use "Relative time" and "Time shift" in Grafana "Query options" so it will query future data

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am using **Grafana 10**.

I have a simple panel using **Elasticsearch** as a data source.

I'd like to specify a custom time range for this particular panel, independent from the Dashboard time picker, so I'm trying to use **Query options**, **Relative time** and **Time shift**.

It works well when I'm querying **yesterday** or **today**, but I cannot make it work when I try to do the same for **tomorrow**.

For **yesterday**:

- Relative time: `now/d`
- Time shift: `1d/d`

For **today**:

- Relative time: `now/d`
- Time shift: `0d/d`

I would like to repeat the same thing for **tomorrow** and I don't see a way how to do it.

I tried:

**Try #1**

- Relative time: `now/d`
- Time shift: `+1d/d`

It fails with error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueOf')*

**Try #1**

- Relative time: `now+1d/d`
- Time shift: `0d/d`

Here, the `Time from` becomes than `Time to`.

---

I'd like to understand if this is something:

1. which is not possible by design because it is wrong, or a bad practice;
2. it should work but maybe it is a bug;
3. i'm doing something wrong, and maybe someone can help me out with some hints on how to achieve this.

**Try #1**

- Relative time: now/d
- Time shift: +1d/d

It fails with error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueOf')

**Try #1**

- Relative time: now+1d/d
- Time shift: 0d/d Here, the Time from becomes than Time to.

---

#### Update

As @markalex suggested, `0d+1d/d` does exactly the job I was looking for.

Comment: As mentioned in [this FR comments](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/10395) you can use `0d+1d`. It looks like `0d+1d/d` also works.

Comment: @markalex your suggestion works perfectly! This is exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks!